# Powershell compare huge directory tree of docs and only move new and updated

Tags: powershell, robocopy

Putting a plan together for moving 70k files between servers for a document mgmt system.  1200 folders is what I believe exist today.

Doing the initial copy is a no brainer.  XCopy or RoboCopy.

How do I identify any new files as well as newer version of same file?  Documents are autocad based.

TIA

Comment: are you syncing one way or two-way? if one way: what about using robocopys mirror `/mir` function? I haven't tested it on this scale though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at /D parameter of xcopy :

```
/D:mm-dd-yyyy
```

Copy files changed on or after the specified date.
            **If no date is given, copy only files whose
            source date/time is newer than the destination time.**

Answer (score 1):

`robocopy SRC DST /l` will list all new and changed files on both sides. Add `/e` to include new empty folders as well. Add `/it` to include tweaked files (same size and date, but different attributes).